# Netdiscover not showing any results

Tags: kali-linux

I'm running Kali Linux in VirtualBox. When I run the netdiscover command it's not showing any results at all. I'm trying to use it to try Kioptrix level 1 (also running in VirtualBox). Any suggestions would help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with libpcap. This thread from the Kali forums had the answer: https://forums.kali.org/archive/index.php/t-45949.html

Answer (score 0):

In the settings of VirtualBox, what is the "Attached to:" setting on the Kali VM's network adapter?

You'll need to set it to "Bridged Adapter" to use any ARP-based tools. If the "NAT" or "NAT Network" mode is used, those tools will only be able to probe the virtual NAT network segment created by VirtualBox, instead of the real network outside the host computer.

(Based on the information in the comments:) Your version of VirtualBox might be different from mine. `wlp3s0` is the WiFi adapter of the host system, `enp0s25` is the wired NIC on the host system.

The easiest way is probably switch both VMs to Bridged Adapter and select (on both of them) `wlp3s0` if you're using wireless network and `enp0s25` if using wired. This will allow both Kali and Kioptrix VMs to get an IP address using your network's existing DHCP server. In this configuration, the Kali and Kioptrix VMs should be able to communicate with each other and also with the internet.

Another alternative would be to select "Internal Network" (and probably either `vmnet1` or `vmnet8`; the same one for both VMs) and then either set up a DHCP server on Kali or set static IPs on both Kali and Kioptrix VMs. In this setup, the VMs will be isolated from the external network, so you can't accidentally launch attacks against other computers in your local network, or on the internet. But setting this up is a bit more work.

Comment: It's showing multiple options for the bridged adaptor, which do I select?

Comment: What are those options? If the host system has multiple network interfaces, there is probably one bridged adapter corresponding to each of the host's physical interfaces. Pick the one that corresponds to the physical interface to the network you wish to use Kali's tools in.  If you meant the selection of the type of the virtual NIC to present to the VM, leave it to the default value unless you *know* you need to change it.

Comment: Under Bridged Adapter, I can select wlp3s0, enp0s25, vmnet1 or vmnet8. Do I change the setting to Bridged Adapter on both the Kali VM and the Kioptrix VM? I know that these are probably stupid questions but I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

In Kali Linux 2020, you need to make sure you have installed a more recent version of *libpcap0.8*.

In my case I fixed the issue with ensuring this version was installed from the kali-rolling repository:

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy libpcap0.8
libpcap0.8:
  Installed: 1.9.1-4
  Candidate: 1.9.1-4
  Version table:
 *** 1.9.1-4 500
        500 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Also netdiscover has a newer version, but upgrading that package alone doesn't fix the problem. The problem is in *libpcap0.8*.

Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libcap0.8 netdiscover` after you have verified you are using the rolling repo (see https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/)